# Cant run shell in Ubuntu server 18.04.2 LTS but it does run in Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I have been working in a shell at Ubuntu desktop, I also did a detailed [spell check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to it, after that I kept testing it and made sure every single line was working as intended, besides a couple directory mistakes (that will need to be changed in the server), everything seems OK

And now I'm trying to run it in a clean virtual machine with ubuntu server, so I mounted a shared folder to get access to my shell, gave permissions to execute to all users, and tried running it and surprise, it doesn't run at all

To get the interpreter to run the script i need to remove the first line **#!/bin/bash** and use **source** instead of **./** to run the shell (named master.sh)

And now that i can get it to run I keep getting this error

[image]

A common error for [wrong syntax on if statements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87776/shell-script-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-else), that I know its been fixed by me and tested it using spellcheck

After that I tried to purge any other non Unix character using

[image]

I know for a fact that both OS are using BASH as an interpreter (I checked)

Here's an minimum example of the code of the 2 "IF conditions" that I can identify stopping the script, if anyone wants to look at it

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e DB_conf ]
    then
            read -p "Use DB_conf settings? [y/n]: " -n 1 -r
                if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
                then
                    STUFF
                else           #This is line 39
                    STUFF2 
                fi
    else        
        MORE STUFF
    fi
```

Why is ubuntu server showing this error but not the desktop one (where it actually works)?

Comment: The `sed` command to replace CRLF line endings with LF endings would be `sed -i 's/\r$//' 02_master.sh`

Comment: @steeldriver just tested `sed -i 's/\r$//' 02_master.sh` seems to actually  do something however i get a **sed: couldn't open a temporary file ./sedC35t0D: Permission denied** even after a chmod 777 to all the scripts in the folder, i think it might have to do with the virtual machine user not being the actual owner of the shared folder

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the sed command has too many or too few /, see the comment by @steeldriver for a better sed command.

Alternatively, you can open the script in vim and view non-printable characters with [esc] `:set list` to see if you have any carriage returns. If that isn't the issue we'll need more context in order to solve the bash error.

Comment: Agreed - if `vim` is not an option, the OP could use `cat -A 02_master.sh` to see line-endings and non-printing characters

Comment: @steeldriver I also made sure no line-endings where present on every line, but i did it using nano, i might use vim to double check and verify twice